# PowerShell 2 Command To List Only Local Disabled User Accounts

Tags: windows, powershell, command

I am restricted to PowerShell version 2, I have crafted a command that lists out all of the accounts in the disabled state:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount | where{$_.Disabled -eq "True"} | select Name, Disabled
```

This works well, however, it also lists DC user accounts, I am only trying to query local users.

Is there any way to query only local user accounts in the disabled state?

Comment: Hmmm, never dealt with the UserAccount class. Can you pipe it to a `Get-Member` and see what options return for you?

Comment: You can do this for virtually any .Net class that returns objects. You just have to use one and call for only one object, and pipe to Get-Member as normal. If you don't want to do this manually. You can download and use this Powershell tool to browse namespaces locally.  ---  [Coretech WMI/CIM and PowerShell Browser](https://blog.ctglobalservices.com/powershell/kaj/coretech-wmi-and-powershell-browser/) [Tool Images](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27coretech+wmi+and+powershell+explorer%27&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True and Disabled=True" | Select-Object Name, Disabled
```

Comment: Ahh nice, that's what I wanted to try an accomplish, just want sure what property it would be. My dang posh is just super slow lol

Comment: @AbrahamZinala next time I'll give you a bit more time :)

Comment: No need, my query is still going lol thanks tho(:

Comment: Both of you are legends! :)

Answer (score 2):

Old school Windows Tools still work, even from PowerShell regardless of version.

```
wmic useraccount get Name,Disabled
```

or

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoExit', '-NoProfile', '-Command  &{ "wmic useraccount get Name,Disabled" }'
# Results
<#
Disabled  Name
TRUE      Administrator
...
#>
```

***Update*** for proof relative to your comment...

> ***...it seems to give me an Invalid GET Expression error message on
> PowerShell version 2***

...

```
C:\>powershell -version 2.0 -nologo -noprofile
PS C:\> (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.9151
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1


PS C:\> wmic useraccount get Name
Name
Administrator
...

PS C:\> wmic useraccount get Disabled
Disabled
TRUE
..

PS C:\> wmic useraccount get "Name,Disabled"
Disabled  Name
TRUE      Administrator
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, this works well on PowerShell version 5, however, it seems to give me an Invalid GET Expression error message on PowerShell version 2.

Comment: Sounds like something is odd about your environment. As it does work in PSv2 mode on WIn10.  As I said, I've not touched an original PSv2 system in years. I have no legacy WinOS (Win XP SP3 WS 2003 SP2, Win Vista SP1/SP2, Windows Vista SP2, or Windows Server 2008 SP1/SP2), that came with v2. You could just shell out to `cmd.exe` and have the results returned back to your Powershell session as welll.